# Update base data when spark streaming

Tags: streaming, spark-streaming

Foy my scenario, the data a will be read from kafka in the realtime way using spark streaming. Based on the data A from an rdbms(MySQL,etc), which is the accumulated T+1 data, the computation will be done, result=A+a,for example.
The next the accumlated data is B, the computation will be result = B+a

My Question is how can I sum the data based on the T+1 data from rdbms.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We finally worked it out by using a redis. Import data from rdbms everyday, and update the data in redis, and export the data to rdbms result table at the end of every day. Close this question, Thank you.